# Create a Basic Registration Form

Tags: sharepoint-online

We’re using SP2013 and will be hosting a few trainings, and want to create a site where users can self register using their name, Email, and employee id.  There are no other limitations for the amount of users that can register for each.  All of the users that will sign up will have access to the site and are internal employees. Is there an OOTB or simple solution that could provide this functionality?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(First, a simple LIST should suffice for this task) If there is more than one training, have a CHOICE column with a drop down list for the users to choose which training they want to sign up for (make the choices correlate to the training sessions, of course).  After that, the rest of the fields should be the usual NAME, EMAIL, etc.  If you want to keep it simple, under the LIST option in the ribbon, choose 'Alert Me' under Share & Track, and set up an email alert for you each time someone signs up for a session, if you like.  (This can get cumbersome, if you have lots of people signing up at one time, though, so be judicious in this choice.)

Comment: Thank you DanJ!! I have already created the list and it looks good. The only issue I have is the dates/times are showing for all of the trainings in the drop-down menu. Is there a way that I can filter this? For example, if I sign up and select module 1 in the drop-down, when I go to the date and time column it should only populate the date and times for module 1. Or would it be easier for me to just create separate lists for each training?

Comment: There are potentially a couple of ways you can do this.  You could indeed make a separate list for each training, but I honestly don't think it should come to that.  A workflow may be an option, although I'm not sure on the specifics.  Also using JS could also be another solution (again, I'm not sure on the specifics).

Answer (score -1):

You will have to enable FBA (Form based authentication) with SQL membership provider or similar membership service if you are enabling the site for external users. Site need to be set up for anonymous access. There's no registration page in the default settings in SP2013. You will have to set up a page with custom solution to enable user registration.

Comment: As I stated, it will only be for internal users who already have access.  I am looking for guidance on how to setup the registration page for the new users...as in how do I achieve the custom solution you speak of.